# "sudo su && somecommand" doesn't run somecommand

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, command-line

I have created a Jenkins job today, what it does is the Jenkins user should log into another server and run two commands seperated by `&&`:

```
ssh -i /creds/jenkins jenkins@servername.com "sh -c 'sudo su && df'"
```

The loging part works fine, then it runs the sudo su command and becomes root but it never runs the second command (i.e. `df`).

I even did this manually and from the Jenkins machine logged into the other server (servername). Then ran `sh -c "sudo su && df"` with no luck.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sudo su` starts a new shell; the command doesn't exit until that shell exits. Most importanly, `df` doesn't run in that shell. You probably just want `ssh -i /creds/jenkins jenkins@servername.com 'sudo df'`.

Comment: Since when do you need root privileges to run `df`?

Comment: Actually, the second command is not df. I typed that as an example. I would like to run this command: lxc exec containername bash

Comment: `sudo lxc exec containername bash`, then. No `&&` called for, and no need for a login shell (as created by either `su -` or, preferably, `sudo -i`) unless `lxc` is depending on environment variables being set up in dotfiles.

Comment: ...to be clear, when you run `sudo su` interactively and get a prompt back, when you're at that prompt, both `sudo` and `su` (or a process they used `exec` to replace themselves with) *are still running*, and they (or a successor process their PID was replaced with -- which can be the process `sudo` or `su` was told to execute) keep running until you exit that prompt. This is why when you write a command that waits for `sudo` (and the copy of `su` that you told `sudo` to start) to exit before it goes on to do something else, it fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to run the `df` command as root, you should instead do `sudo df`.

This is because with `sudo su && df`, you are basically executing `sudo su` first and then `df`.

Also make sure, your jenkins user can be sudo without password.

Answer (score 2):

The `sudo su` launches a second shell, and the command containing the `&& df` is waiting to be executed in the non-root shell, just after the `sudo su` shell exits successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you're looking for:

```
sh -c 'sudo su - root -c "df"'
```

**Edit:** please note that I don't normally use or advocate the use of `sudo su - root -c` type of constructions. However, I have seen rare cases in which a  program doesn't work properly when called via `sudo/gksudo`, but does work properly when called via `su/gksu` -- in such cases, a given user should **try to use `sudo -i` first**, and if that does not work, one might have to resort to `sudo su - root -c` or similar, as a workaround of sorts to deal with a "misbehaving" program. Since the OP used some similar syntax on his post, I assumed that his case could be such a workaround case, so I maintained the `sudo su - root -c` type of structure on my answer.

Comment: `sudo du -c root -c "df"` is essentially the same as `sudo df`

Comment: They are very similar, but I have seen cases in which a program will not work with sudo/gksudo but it would work with su/gksu (I have no explanation why that would happen, but I did see it happening).

Comment: Yes, but here you're depending on *both* `sudo` and `su` working, rather than depending on only one or the other functioning. Worst of both worlds.

Comment: ...now, there *are* distinctions -- `su - root` generates a login shell by default, so you get all your environment variables, which might be the explanation for the "cases" you refer to -- but you can get that with `sudo` as well by using the `-i` argument.

Comment: ...and frankly, sometimes a login shell is The Wrong Thing! If you don't trust a service's home directory not to be modified by an attacker, you surely don't want a login shell to be run when invoking a command as that service's user. Understanding exactly what your code does (and thus why something does or doesn't work) is essential to making informed decisions about which behaviors you do or don't want. Also, typically, you'll have distinct PAM configurations for `sudo` and `su` -- invoking both during a single command is rarely behavior one would intentionally choose.

Comment: @Charles yes, using `sudo` and `su` together makes you dependent on two things instead of one (more chances for a problem). But that's how the OP constructed it, and I just made his construction work. I would be afraid of suggesting a different construction here because I have seen cases in which a program would work with su/gksu but not with sudo/gksudo, and I don't know if using `sudo -i` would work on such case. I remember I did troubleshoot one of those occasions and came to the conclusion that the problem was on the program being called. Personally, I never use `sudo su`.

Comment: I remember one instance of such cases: the command `update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, which updates the flash plugin on chromium browsers on some Linux distributions. If you put this command on a bash script (not via terminal) and call it via `gksu` it works, if you call it via `gksudo` it hangs. I have seen more cases than this one, including with `sudo su` itself, but I can't remember then right now. It shouldn't happen, but it does. My theory here is that the program being called checks to see if you are root and somehow gets it wrong it when you call via sudo/gksudo.

Comment: @JamilSaid, I already described what happens: `su - foo`, and thus `sudo su - foo`, creates a login shell, whereas merely `sudo foo` directly execs the target program; consequently, environment variables from the user's dotfiles aren't set in the latter case. And I already described how to work around it -- with `sudo -i`.

Comment: I bet you're right that `sudo -i` would work (and thus be a much better answer here), but I can't be 100% sure because I don't have such a `sudo su` "anomally" that I can replicate and test it. However, I do can replicate the `gksu` (works) `gksudo` (doesn't work) case I mentioned on this thread. Would you have any suggestion for a program that works when called via `gksu` but not via `gksudo` (both via gui launcher)? I looked for `gksudo -i` but I don't believe that this option exists.

Answer (score 0):

when you did `sudo su && df` , `sudo su` will start a child process immediately without waiting for the `&& df` part of the command to execute , when you hit `Ctrl + D` it exits the child process and enters the parent shell , that's when your && df will execute. You should do this using here strings, it might not be the best option but it works and it does not start a new child process

```
sh -c "sudo su" <<<df
```

note: don't surround <<< df with any quotes